# No result for given regex in vb

Tags: regex, vb.net

My regex code for Visual Basic is not returning output for following code:

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("<table class=""listing"">.*?</table>")
Dim match As Match = regex.Match(str, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
If match.Success Then
    MsgBox(match.Value)
End If
```

Input is like this:

```html
<table class="listing">
<tr> 
<th width="85%">
Name
</th>
<th width="15%">
Day Added
</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please consider http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/11683.

Comment: @GSerg That's the funniest thing I've seen in a long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple errors:

First, you are using it wrong: When using regexInstance.Match(), the second parameter is the start-offset - not the Regex Options.

To use Regex Options, use the Static Version of `Match()` along with a String Pattern:

```
Dim regexStr As String = "<table class=""listing"">.*?</table>"
Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(Str, regexStr, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

or add the options to the constructor:

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("<table class=""listing"">.*?</table>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Singleline)
Dim match As Match = regex.Match(str)
```

Second, you need to Provide `RegexOptions.SingleLine` additional to `IgnoreCase`.
(So: `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.SingleLine`)

The HTML String contains Linebreaks, which your Regex simple doesn't match.

In Single-Line Mode the `.` will also match New Lines https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Singleline

putting all together:

```
Dim Str As String = "<table class=""listing"">" & System.Environment.NewLine & "test" & System.Environment.NewLine & "</table>"

Dim regexStr As String = "<table class=""listing"">.*?</table>"
Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(Str, regexStr, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Singleline)

If match.Success Then
    MsgBox(match.Value)
End If
```

Comment: still not returning any output